# Abrir dropDown por cima da div

Tags: html, css, front-end

Olá, tenho um dropDown feito com ui-select, que não abre por cima do restante do site.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como podem ver ele abre somente até o limite da div 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

já tentei com os exemplos que achei em sites.
exemplos: position: absolute, z-index: 99999, overflow: visible,
em nem um caso obtive sucesso.

Código do ui-select:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <strong>Perfis: </strong>
 <ui-select ng-model="acao.perfis"
            multiple
            title="Selecione um perfil">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Perfil" allow-clear="true">{{$item.nome}}      </ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices  repeat="perfil in acoesCtrl.perfis | filter: $select.search">
      {{perfil.nome}}
  </ui-select-choices>
  <ui-select-no-choice>
     Nenhum registro encontrado
  </ui-select-no-choice>
  </ui-select>
```

Minha dúvida é:
    Como abrir o dropDown sobre a div?

Comment: Qual o OVERFLOW dessa div.col-md-6?

Comment: a div tem a classe col-md-6 do bootstrap, que até onde sei não tem overflow e a classe: gc-panel                                                                           .gc-panel {
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}

Comment: inspeciona o elemento e descobre qual o último OVERFLOW que se aplicou nela, pois o atributo que impede que um elemento estique, ou ultrapasse, a altura é o overflow

Comment: o elemento tem apenas o overflow: overflow-x: hidden; que ao removê-lo, apenas remove o scroll do drop down. adicionando um outro tipo de overflow diferente, não tem efeito algum.